# Pivot Table Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have my table like down below. Actually players ranked by their total points for team 1 and 2.

```
teamNO  playername
===================
1        Joe
1        Jack
1        Micheal
1        Ken
1        Fendy
2        Helen
2        Mike  
2        Chris
2        George
2        Dan
```

I want to write my table like down one but I am getting only 1 row. I think due to teamno is only 1 and 2.  Is there any way to  achieve this? Thanks in advance

```
Rank   Team1          Team2
================================
1       Joe           Helen
2       Jack          Mike
3       Micheal       Chris
4       Ken           George
5       Fendy         Dan
```

Comment: As it stands, no you can't.  There is no explicit rank or otherwise indicator of points indicating a rank basis to join.  Are there any other underlying table sources that are used to determine the rankings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 ;WITH cte AS(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES
    (1, 'Joe'),
    (1, 'Jack'),
    (1, 'Micheal'),
    (1, 'Ken'),
    (1, 'Fendy'),
    (2, 'Helen'),
    (2, 'Mike '),
    (2, 'Chris'),
    (2, 'George'),
    (2, 'Dan')
    ) as t(teamNO, playername)),
    final AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TeamNo ORDER BY TeamNo) AS [Rank],*
    FROM cte)

SELECT f1.[Rank], f1.playername as Team1, f2.playername as Team2
FROM final f1
LEFT JOIN final f2 ON f1.[Rank] = f2.[Rank] and f1.TeamNo != f2.TeamNo
WHERE f1.teamNO = 1
```

Results:

```
Rank                 Team1   Team2
-------------------- ------- -------
1                    Joe     Helen
2                    Jack    Mike 
3                    Micheal Chris
4                    Ken     George
5                    Fendy   Dan

(5 row(s) affected)
```